# C# Error with 'continue'

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean-logic

I'm trying to use an if statement with a bool that will make it that if a code runs once it will not run again. Here is the code I am using.

```
int random = Program._random.Next(0, 133);

if (random < 33) {
   bool done = false;

   if(done)
   {
      continue; // Error is shown for this statement
   }

   Console.WriteLine("Not done!");
   done = true;
}
```

The error that Visual Studio is displaying is: "No enclosing loop out of which to break or continue".

Comment: The error says it all.

Comment: I realized I need the bool done = false; outside of the if statement, I did so. Still getting the error.

Comment: Okay @deathismyfriend... how can I fix it?

Comment: What he is saying is that you don't have a loop anywhere, only an if statement(two actually). No while, or for statement, etc.

Comment: You have a continue that isn't inside the loop.  If you read the error it tells you exactly that. Remove the continue and there will be no error. Also to make code only run once you need to move the bool to outside of the method and make it global. If it is inside a loop then it needs to be moved outside of the loop. The done = true; should also be inside the if(!done) { } block.

Comment: `The continue statement passes control to the next iteration of the enclosing while, do, for, or foreach statement in which it appears.` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029. Then you shold use `if(!done){...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the class/method requirements, you could possibly reverse your logic:

```
 if (!done)
 {
   Console.WriteLine("Not done!");
   done = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a continue only inside a loop. So you must live without this:

```
int random = Program._random.Next(0, 133);
if(random < 33)
{
    bool done = false;
    if(!done)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Not done!");
        done = true;
    }
}
```

In this case, you should reverse the if with `if (!done) { ... }`

Comment: Seriously?  Done is a local variable you set to false.    Done does nothing in you your code.

Comment: Of course you're right! I took this example as it is in the question. So I guess/hope this was just for making the code easier. Don't blame me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `continue` like that, it can only be used in a loop. The `continue` statement will go to the end of the loop and continue with the next iteration, without a loop there is no end of the loop to go to.

You can use `else` instead:

```
if (done) {
  // anything to do?
} else {
  Console.WriteLine("Not done!");
  done = true;
}
```

If there is nothing to do if the variable is true, you can just reverse the expression instead:

```
if (!done) {
  Console.WriteLine("Not done!");
  done = true;
}
```

Note: You need to store the variable `done` outside the scope. Now you have a local variable that is always set to `false`, so the code will never be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is telling you that [`continue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1.aspx) is ineffective here. It simply has nothing to do, and doesn't know *where* to continue. It is meant to be used within the iteration of a loop.